# Output a nice "block" character with ncurses and C++?

Tags: c++, c, ncurses

I'm writing a console app in c++ using ncurses and I'd like to output a solid ascii block. It'd basically tape up all of the area that would normally be reserved for white space of a normal character. Is there an ASCII character I'm missing or a library function I haven't seen in the manual?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ASCII is only 7-bit. If you are willing to go with 8-bit, there is the Code Page 437:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437

Then there is Unicode, which opens a whole new world of characters...

Comment: Thanks - the character sets available have always confused me a bit.

Comment: @Darkenor: The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!) - Joel on Software http://bit.ly/h0P05m