# Curses Fill Block

Tags: c++, ncurses, curses

I'm working with the curses library for c++ and was wondering how I would go about filling a block instead of inserting a character. I want to just create a colored block but can't find any way to do this online.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the character encoding/codepage used, you can use the block character (e.g. code 0xDB on codepage 437). See also [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5117171/output-a-nice-block-character-with-ncurses-and-c).